# Most efficient way of reading data from a stream

Tags: c#, performance, stream

I have an algorithm for encrypting and decrypting data using symmetric encryption. anyways when I am about to decrypt, I have:

```
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
```

I have to read data from the cs CryptoStream and place that data into a array of bytes. So one method could be:

```
  System.Collections.Generic.List<byte> myListOfBytes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<byte>();

   while (true)
   {
                int nextByte = cs.ReadByte();
                if (nextByte == -1) break;
                myListOfBytes.Add((Byte)nextByte);
   }
   return myListOfBytes.ToArray();
```

another technique could be:

```
ArrayList chuncks = new ArrayList();

byte[] tempContainer = new byte[1048576];

int tempBytes = 0;
while (tempBytes < 1048576)
{
    tempBytes = cs.Read(tempContainer, 0, tempContainer.Length);
    //tempBytes is the number of bytes read from cs stream. those bytes are placed
    // on the tempContainer array

    chuncks.Add(tempContainer);

}

// later do a for each loop on chunks and add those bytes
```

I cannot know in advance the length of the stream cs:

[image]

or perhaps I should implement my stack class. I will be encrypting a lot of information therefore making this code efficient will save a lot of time

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You could read in chunks:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    byte[] result = stream.ToArray();
    // TODO: do something with the result
}
```

Comment: quick question... why did you place everything inside the using statement? what does the using statement mean?

Comment: @Tono Nam, it ensures that the Dispose method of IDisposable resources such as Streams is always called in order to free any unmanaged resources that they might hold even in case of an exception and thus avoid memory leaks in your code. That's a fundamental concept that I invite you reading about on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx Also you should wrap your `CryptoStream` into a using statement.

Comment: Also you should use `CopyTo()` if this is .NET 4 ;-)

Comment: For more another performance improvement you can use `byte[] result = stream.GetBuffer();` instead, however you need to use `stream.Length` instead of `result.Length` as the buffer will often be larger than the actual result set.

Answer (score 32):

Since you are storing everything in memory anyway you can just use a `MemoryStream` and [**`CopyTo()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    cs.CopyTo(ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

`CopyTo()` will require .NET 4

Comment: Can't believe I missed this my whole life

Comment: Maybe I should open a question for this: if I call cs.CopyTo() and there is not readable data, will it wait for more data to become available? (As in a network stream)