# Get Length of Data Available in NetworkStream

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, networkstream

I would like to be able to get the length of the data available from a TCP network stream in C# to set the size of the buffer before reading from the network stream. There is a `NetworkStream.Length` property but it isn't implemented yet, and I don't want to allocate an enormous size for the buffer as it would take up too much space. The only way I though of doing it would be to precede the data transfer with another telling the size, but this seems a little messy. What would be the best way for me to go about doing this.

Comment: The usual way of reading a stream is to do it in small portions at a time, (e.g. 512 bytes) and when `0` is returned from the `Read` method, that means there's no more data. Is there a reason you aren't doing this, or were you not aware of this?

Comment: I was not aware, could you give me a small code example? If you post it as an answer I will likely accept it.

Comment: The other technique is to store the length of the message before the data of the message. Then read in, for example, a four byte length, then translate the four bytes to an integer and read in up to that many bytes.

Comment: Again, could you please give me a code example in the form of an answer, I'll evaluate the two and see which is more efficient. That is an idea I was thinking of but I was unsure on how to go about this.

Comment: A TCP stream is endless.  Discrete messages and/or lengths are simply a matter of software protocol imposed by the programmer.  Even if you know the overall length of the data that is expected, there is no guarantee of how the data sent will be grouped together when it arrives as the software/hardware along the transmission route can break up or join the data together.  This is par for the course in TCP applications.  You simply declare a byte array of reasonable size and accumulate the received data until you have determined that "all" the data has arrived (as per your established protocol).

Comment: Exactly. As @Idle_Mind has shown, your question is actually completely meaningless.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When accessing [`Stream`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), you usually read and write data in small chunks (e.g. a kilobyte or so), or use a method like [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) that does that for you.

This is an example using `CopyTo` to copy the contents of a stream to another stream and return it as a `byte[]` from a method, using an automatically-sized buffer.

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    networkStream.CopyTo(ms);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

This is code that reads data in the same way, but more manually, which might be better for you to work with, depending on what you're doing with the data:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
int bytesRead;
while((bytesRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    //do something with data in buffer, up to the size indicated by bytesRead
}
```

(the basis for these code snippets came from [Most efficient way of reading data from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542059/most-efficient-way-of-reading-data-from-a-stream))

Comment: This is great! I'll use this to write to a memory stream until all the data has arrived.

Comment: I actually modified your code a bit, to make sure that I have the entire object before continuing, essentially, the first 8 bytes of the packet are the size, and it will continue reading what it can until it has the same amount of bytes in memory as it is expecting.

Answer (score 3):

There is no inherent length of a network stream. You will either have to send the length of the data to follow from the other end or read all of the incoming data into a different stream where you can access the length information.

Comment: In many protocols the byte length of the message must be set by the sender in a message header with 1, 2 or 4 bytes

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, you can't really be sure all the data is read by the socket yet, more data might come in at any time. This is try even if you somehow do know how much data to expect, say if you have a package header that contains the length. the whole packet might not be received yet.

If you're reading arbitrary data (like a file perhaps) you should have a buffer of reasonable size (like 1k-10k or whatever you find to be optimal for your scenario) and then write the data to a file as its read from the stream.

```
var buffer = byte[1000];
var readBytes = 0;
using(var netstream = GetTheStreamSomhow()){
    using(var fileStream = (GetFileStreamSomeHow())){
        while(netstream.Socket.Connected) //determine if there is more data, here we read until the socket is closed
        {
            readBytes = netstream.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
            fileStrem.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Or just use `CopyTo` like Tim suggested :) Just make sure that all the data has indeed been read, including data that hasn't gotten across the network yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the lenght of the incoming data first.
For example:
You have `data = byte[16]` you want to send. So at first you send the 16 and define on the server, that this length is always 2 (because 16 has two characters). Now you know that the `incomingLength = 16`. You can wait now for data of the lenght `incomingLength`.

Answer (score 0):

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bf.Serialize(ms, pars); // pars - some array of standart (not user) types
byte[] buff = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int32)ms.Length);
socket.Send(buff);
socket.Receive(buff);  // read for server answer
if (BitConverter.ToInt32(buff, 0) == 200)
{
    NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket);
    ms.CopyTo(ns);
}
```

Comment: It feels a bit difficult to understand what you are trying to answer. Could you please add more details and look at [how do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)