# UWP TCP read large messages

Tags: c#, string, sockets, tcp, uwp

I'm trying to read strings from a TCP socket. The server (which I have no access to) sends strings that can be smaller (only 3 chars) or longer( > 10.000 chars) than the BUFFER_SIZE.

For that I'm using the following method, which runs continuously in a separate task (thread). As soon as it reads a valid string it triggers an event, which the main task is subscribed to [...]

The cTS (CancellationTokenSource) is required for external cancellation of the reader.ReadAsync(...)

```
private readonly int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
private StreamSocket tcpSocket;
private StreamReader reader;
private CancellationTokenSource cTS;

public string readMessageFromServer()
{
    string result = "";
    while(true)
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        cTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
        reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE).Wait(cTS.Token);
        string data = new string(buffer);
        if (data.IndexOf("\0") >= 0 || reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            return result + data.Substring(0, data.IndexOf("\0"));
        }
        result += data;
    }
}
```

My Code works just fine for strings with a length < 4096 chars, but as soon as the string gets longer than 4096 chars it fails (won't detect the message end). It waits until it receives a new string < 4096 chars, concatenates both strings and returns them as one string.

Is there a way to get the actual length of a string and read them successively?

```
reader.ReadLineAsync()
```

Will not work, because the strings can contain "\n" or "\r\n" and the server won't add line breaks at the end of each string

Comment: Does the server add "\0" at the end of each string?

Comment: No, the "\0" is the default value of each char in the `buffer` array. For example one resulting sting could be: somestring\0\0\0\0\0\0

Comment: So what happen when server sends data with length equals to 4096? There is probably no "\0" after buffer... but no further data comes.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason why I need a way to know, how long every message is or when all bytes got read.

Comment: The server must tell the the size of the message. Client cannot guess the length if the server does not give a hint. All protocols that are built above TCP either has fixed length messages or adds a message length to transferred data. For example the http adds the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Hmm... that's unfortunate. Isn't there a way to get the size of the unread buffer? Because normally the transport layer pushes data only in bursts to the application layer.

Comment: There is no reliable way to get size of available data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387979/get-length-of-data-available-in-networkstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out to read long messages:
I had to user `DataReader` and `DataWriter` instead of `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

```
/// <summary>
/// How many characters should get read at once max.
/// </summary>
private static readonly int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

private StreamSocket socket;
private DataReader dataReader;
private DataWriter dataWriter;

public string readNextString() {
    string result = "";
    readingCTS = new CancellationTokenSource();

    try {
        uint readCount = 0;

        // Read the first batch:
        Task < uint > t = dataReader.LoadAsync(BUFFER_SIZE).AsTask();
        t.Wait(readingCTS.Token);
        readCount = t.Result;

        if (dataReader == null) {
            return result;
        }

        while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0) {
            result +=dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
        }

        // If there is still data left to read, continue until a timeout occurs or a close got requested:
        while (!readingCTS.IsCancellationRequested && readCount >= BUFFER_SIZE) {
            t = dataReader.LoadAsync(BUFFER_SIZE).AsTask();
            t.Wait(100, readingCTS.Token);
            readCount = t.Result;
            while (dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0) {
                result += dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(AggregateException) {}
    catch(NullReferenceException) {}

    return result;
}
```