# Defending against no data

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I have this line of code:

```
NetworkStream tcpStream;
return IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(new BinaryReader(tcpStream).ReadInt32());
```

Occasionally, there is no data to read and that lines throws an exception.

```
System.IO.EndOfStreamException
  HResult=0x80070026
  Message=Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.IO.__Error.EndOfFile()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.FillBuffer(Int32 numBytes)
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadInt32()
   ...
```

The `Length` property also doesn't seem to help. `DataAvailable` is highly unreliable. How do I defend against an empty message?

Comment: could you post the whole snippet and the exception please?

Comment: See edited post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387979/get-length-of-data-available-in-networkstream

Comment: I have no idea how that link is supposed to help

Comment: It says that networkstreams dont indicate their length, but - when you copy the content to a memorystream, you could for example check if its length in bytes is > sizeof(int) [or > 4, which is the size of an int32 ] before attempting to read a 4 byte int from it..

you could however, also just catch the endofstreamexception ... or in short.. you need to read it into another stream to know its length

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need that?
You can use a StreamReader and a StreamWriter to easily send and receive a string. Then, you can handle that data, and get your int.

```
        static int Receive(NetworkStream nw)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(nw, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        static void Send(NetworkStream nw, int num)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(nw, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(num.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Tested and works.