# C# Owin WebApp: Parsing POST Requests?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, post, owin

I would like some help on parsing HTTP POST requests in a C# console application. The app runs a 'web-server' using Owin. Details of the application are available [here](http://code.google.com/p/sensor-mon-http/wiki/PageName) and the current 'stable version' of the relevant code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/sensor-mon-http/source/browse/trunk/SensorMonHTTP/Program.cs).

I am extending the above application to enable configuration through the web UI. For example, the app currently reports a large number of parameters. I would like the end-user to be able to select which parameters get reported over the network. Towards this, I made some modifications to the code above:

```
    using Microsoft.Owin;
    using Owin;
    .........
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SensorMonHTTP.WebIntf))]
    .........
    .........
    namespace SensorMonHTTP
    {
      ...
      public class WebIntf
      {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
          app.Run(context =>
          {
            var ConfigPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/config");
            var ConfigApplyPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/apply_config");
            var SensorPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/");
            if (context.Request.Path == SensorPath) 
            { 
              return context.Response.WriteAsync(GetSensorInfo()); 
              /* Returns JSON string with sensor information */
            }
            else if (context.Request.Path == ConfigPath)
            {
              /* Generate HTML dynamically to list out available sensor 
                 information with checkboxes using Dynatree: Tree3 under 
                 'Checkbox & Select' along with code to do POST under 
                 'Embed in forms' in 
                 http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html */
              /* Final segment of generated HTML is as below:
              <script>
              .....
              $("form").submit(function() {
                var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
                var tree = $("#tree3").dynatree("getTree");
                formData = formData.concat(tree.serializeArray());
                // alert("POST this:\n" + jQuery.param(formData)); 
                // -- This gave the expected string in an alert when testing out
                $.post("apply_config", formData);
                return true ;
              });
              ......
              </script></head>
              <body>
              <form action="apply_config" method="POST">
              <input type="submit" value="Log Selected Parameters">
              <div id="tree3" name="selNodes"></div>
              </body>
              </html>
              End of generated HTML code */
            }
            else if (context.Request.Path == ConfigApplyPath)
            {
              /* I want to access and parse the POST data here */
              /* Tried looking into context.Request.Body as a MemoryStream, 
                 but not getting any data in it. */
            }
          }
        }
        ........
      }
```

Can anyone help me with how the POST data can be accessed in the above code structure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

Since the data returns in KeyValuePair format you can cast it as IEnumerable which looks something like the following:

```
var formData = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync() as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string[]>>;
```

//now you have the list that you can query against

```
var formElementValue = formData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "NameOfYourHtmlFormElement").Value[0]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ReadFormAsync() utility on the IOwinRequest object to read/parse the form parameters.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Run(async context =>
                {
                    //IF your request method is 'POST' you can use ReadFormAsync() over request to read the form 
                    //parameters
                    var formData = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
                    //Do the necessary operation here. 
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract the body Parameters for each content type you can use a method like this:

```
    public async static Task<IDictionary<string, string>> GetBodyParameters(this IOwinRequest request)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (request.ContentType != "application/json")
        {
            var formCollectionTask = await request.ReadFormAsync();

            foreach (var pair in formCollectionTask)
            {
                var value = GetJoinedValue(pair.Value);
                dictionary.Add(pair.Key, value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // read in chunks of 2KB
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
                // TODO: do something with the result
                var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(result);

                foreach(var pair in dict)
                {
                    string value = (pair.Value is string) ? Convert.ToString(pair.Value) : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pair.Value);
                    dictionary.Add(pair.Key, value);
                }
            }
        }

        return dictionary;
    }

    private static string GetJoinedValue(string[] value)
    {
        if (value != null)
            return string.Join(",", value);

        return null;
    }
```

References:
[Most efficient way of reading data from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542059/most-efficient-way-of-reading-data-from-a-stream)

Answer (score 0):

The context.Request.Body is the right place to get POST values, but you need to include a name attribute on the form elements that you want to access. Without the name attribute everything is ignored, and I wasn't able to find a way to access the raw request although it might be possible - never used Owin before.

```
if (context.Request.Path == ConfigPath)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append("<html><head></head><body><form action=\"apply_config\" method=\"post\">");
    sb.Append("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Log Selected Parameters\">");
    sb.Append("<input type=\"text\" value=\"helloworld\" name=\"test\"></input>");
    sb.Append("</body>");
    sb.Append("</html>");

    return context.Response.WriteAsync(sb.ToString());
}
else if (context.Request.Path == ConfigApplyPath)
{
    /* I want to access and parse the POST data here */
    /* Tried looking into context.Request.Body as a MemoryStream, 
        but not getting any data in it. */
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8000];
    int read = 0;

    read = context.Request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    while (read > 0)
    {
        sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
        buffer = new byte[8000];
        read = context.Request.Body.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }


    return context.Response.WriteAsync(sb.ToString());
}
else 
{
    return context.Response.WriteAsync(GetSensorInfo());
    /* Returns JSON string with sensor information */
}
```

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for the response. It turned out that I had a problem in modifying the JavaScript code from the Dynatree example: particularly, the form submit procedure apparently had to return 'false' for the form data to be sent over correctly. I have since resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following works, the trick is to reset the position of the stream.

```
context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
string content = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
```