# C# TcpClient and NetworkStream to send/receive data over TCP. Why not using "using" block and can I read data right after writing it to stream?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, tcpclient, networkstream, using-statement

I am reading documentation on using TcpClient and NetworkStream to write and read from a Tcp connection stream.  But I notice that all Microsoft's documentation is not using "using" block even thought both TcpClient and NetworkStream implement IDisposable.

So, I was wondering why is this.

I also notice in few examples that they write to stream **and then immediately after**, read from the stream.  This does not feel right but I am new to networking but I wrote something like the code below to do exactly that.

While the code works, I am not sure how good and reliable it is though.  Specifically, if data is not available to be read, once I check for it, the execution will move on.  At that point, data may be available for reading but then it is to late, I already passed that point.

My questions are capitalized as code comments below

```
using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient())  // WHY NOT USING?
{
    client.Connect(ip, port);

    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())  // WHY NOT USING?
    {
        byte[] messageBytes = ...;
        if (stream.CanWrite)
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
            stream.Flush();
        }

        // IS THIS DATA GOING TO BE AVAILABLE AT THIS POINT?  
        // IF NOT, THEN YOU WILL HAVE NO OPPORTUNITY TO READ DATA 
        // SINCE NOTHING IS GOING TO TELL YOU WHEN IT IS GOING TO BE AVAILABLE.  
        // BY THE TIME IT IS AVAILABLE, THE EXECUTION MAY PASS THIS POINT, WHAT THEN???
        if (stream.CanRead)  
        {
            byte[] buffer = newe byte[1024];
            int readSoFar = 0;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            while(stream.DataAwailable)
            {
                readSoFar = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                builder.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, readSoFar));
            }

            string msg = builder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `they write to stream and then immediately after, read from the stream` There are two streams per socket. The read and write streams are completely different streams.

Answer (score 2):

`TcpClient`/`NetworkStream`/`Socket` have only one unmanaged resource under the hood. It is socket itself. Your code can have only 1 using block, and you will be ok. In your example, when code leaves `using (NetworkStream)` block, it closes underlying socket, and `TcpClient.Dispose` actually does nothing.

About `Read`/`ReadAsync`. The data is not available immediately. But these methods wait for one of 2 events: data appears on the socket, or other party closes tcp socket. As soon as 1 byte appears on the socket, these functions immediately return result. If another party closes connection, these functions return `0`, which actually indicates end of stream.

Usually you shouldn't use `DataAvailable` property. In your example it can lead to unexpected behavior. You can just use `Read`/`ReadAsync` until they return zero.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how to write it so that data will be available for reading (assuming all goes ok).  The NetworkStream.CanRead is not blocking so it will not wait for anything (at least to the documentation MS provides), it just returns true or false.  That means, if it returns false, my code above will not attempt to read anything.  But then, if next second, data is available, it will be to late since I have passed that if block already?  Thanks

Comment: You misunderstand `CanRead`. It is initialized in `NetworkStream` constructor. If underlying socket is readable, it will be always true, no matter if there is data on the socket, or no. So, in your code `CanRead`/`CanWrite` checks are actually redundant. These properties will be always `true` for your code.

Comment: OK, so are you saying that removing CanRead and CanWrite check will be enough to send request and receive response.  In other words, response will be available to me for reading at the moment I issue ReadAsync even though I do ReadAsync right after WriteAsync?  Thanks again

Comment: @cd491415 right. And remove `DataAvailable` check. Use `ReadAsync` in a loop, and exit when it returns zero.

Comment: Would you mind showing me some code for the reading in the loop.  I am new to the concept of TCP and Tasks which is what I use (await ReadAsync)?  Thanks

Comment: @cd491415 check code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542077/960055 Even though it is not for `NetworkStream`, but concept is the same, and it will work for any `Stream`. All `Stream` implementation should return zero when calling `Read` and it is end of the stream.

Comment: I added UPDATE section with modified while loop but it hangs now on 2nd iteration for some reason

Comment: @cd491415 other party should close the stream in order to exit while loop

Comment: ach, that sucks, I dont have access to other party code.  And this is hanging at the loop all the time.  Anything else I could do to prevent the hanging at least for now until I see what can be done about the "other side" but most likely nothing, it is legacy app?  Much appreciated.

Comment: @cd491415 you can check in the loop if you received full message

Comment: Not sure how to do that and not sure why DataAvailable is not good way to check for availability?  Thanks

Comment: @cd491415 maybe in your case it is good idea to use DataAvailable. But every good protocol build on top of TCP supports 2 behaviors: if there is no data to transfer - close connection, or, there is a simple algorithm to determine message boundaries. It looks like your server doesn't follow these rules.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also see call to WriteAsync causing hanging very often if not surrounded with check for CanWrite.   I think I will put these checks (DataAvailable, CanRead, CanWrite) back.  DataAvailable check definitely helped deal with the loop and CanWrite check seam to be preventing hanging on call to WriteAsync.  I wish MS documentation were better than it is

Comment: I tried setting WriteTimeout and ReadTimeout on NetworkStream to prevent calls to WriteAync, ReadAsync to hang but that does nothing looks like.  Any idea?  Thanks

Comment: @cd491415 just an idea, maybe timeout properties work only with synchronous methods?

Comment: They do, that is correct according to the very bottom of this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.writetimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_WriteTimeout.  But there must be some other way to deal with this

Comment: @cd491415 async methods can accept cancellationtoken