# Download big size file from S3

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

My project needs to download a file which sized around 1.5 GB,  I referred -[This Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html) from AWS documentation however I get `OutOfMemornyException`as soon as file goes beyond 1 GB.

Is there a way like AWS provides Upload in parts, similar for download in parts? Even I see tool S3 Browser downloads in part.

Comment: You want to be streaming a file that size straight to disk. Not storing it in memory. It'd also be advisable to enable the download to resume if the connection drops.

Comment: The problem is on `responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();` you should read part by part, and send to recierver or write it to a file (not to memory). Here is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542059/most-efficient-way-of-reading-data-from-a-stream

Comment: @CihanYakar I tried this earlier, ending up with same exception